# Is it possible to specify the release date in Windows Phone app submission?

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone

Is it possible for me to specify that the app should not be released into the marketplace before a particular date, even if it is approved before that date?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No. But, you can specify that the application shouldn't be automatically made available once the certification process has been passed.

You can then make it publically available at the time/date of your choosing.

Comment: Just to add, once you have it released it can take some time to propagate to all the markets you've selected (up to 24 hours).

Comment: Thanks for the warning keyboardP, it took several hours for my app to appear in my local Marketplace.